# Vue 3: `defineProps` are referencing locally declared variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, vuejs3, vue-sfc

Why I get warning error message:

> `defineProps` are referencing locally declared variables.
> eslint(vue/valid-define-props)

when I use custom validator in props with **SFC** `<script setup>` mode:

```html
<script setup>
import { validateMarkers } from "./hooks"
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  markers: {
    type: [Array, Object],
    validator: validateMarkers
  }
})
</script>
```

My custom validator:

```
export const validateMarkers = (markers) =>
    isNotEmpty(markers)
        ? isObject(markers)
            ? markerValidator(markers)
            : isNotEmptyArray(markers)
            ? markers.every((marker) => markerValidator(marker))
            : error('Undefined type of prop marker')
        : null
```

How I can fix this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is intended to prevent this particular usage (from the [`eslint(vue/valid-define-props)` docs](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-define-props.html)):

```html
<script setup>
  /* ✗ BAD */
  const def = { msg: String }
  defineProps(def)
</script>
```

If you actually [tried to compile that `<script setup>` block](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmNvbnN0IGRlZiA9IHsgbXNnOiBTdHJpbmcgfVxuZGVmaW5lUHJvcHMoZGVmKVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJ2dWVcIjogXCJodHRwczovL3NmYy52dWVqcy5vcmcvdnVlLnJ1bnRpbWUuZXNtLWJyb3dzZXIuanNcIlxuICB9XG59In0=) in a build, the compiler emits this error message that clarifies the reasoning a bit:

> `defineProps()` in `<script setup>` cannot reference locally declared variables because it will be hoisted outside of the `setup()` function. If your component options require initialization in the module scope, use a separate normal `<script>` to export the options instead.

However, importing the validator from a module should actually be fine because there's no concern of hoisting local variables here. In fact, it [compiles without error](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) (see the `JS` tab in the SFC playground).

So I believe this is a false positive that could be ignored with a comment:

```html
<script setup>
import { validateMarkers } from "./hooks"
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  markers: {
    type: [Array, Object],            
    validator: validateMarkers, // eslint-disable-line vue/valid-define-props
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 19):

*@tony19's answer correctly answers OP question and in later versions of eslint and Vue, you don't get that warning for imported bindings.*

#### But if you still get a warning or an error, here is how to fix it!

First, we have to understand that a component can have 2 scopes:

**Setup scope:**

```html
<script setup>
// Setup scope
</script>
```

**Module scope:**

```html
<script>
// Module scope
</script>
```

> #### `defineProps` should not reference local variables declared in setup scope

**Because `defineProps` and `defineEmits` will be hoisted out of setup into module scope**

So the code below will not work:

```html
<script setup>
  const sizes = ['sm', 'md']

  const props = defineProps({
    size: {
      type: String,
      validator: val => sizes.includes(val) // <= Can't reference `sizes`
    }
  })
</script>
```

### How to fix the code above?

**Reference variables that are in the module scope!**

###### Solution 1. Imported bindings are in the local scope:

```html
<script setup>
import { sizes } from './sizes' // <= import it

const props = defineProps({
  size: {
    type: String,
    validator: val => sizes.includes(val) // <= use it
  }
})
</script>
```

###### Solution 2. Variables declared in module scope (not script setup):

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  size: {
    type: String,
    validator: val => sizes.includes(val) // <= sizes from module scope
  }
})
</script>

<script>
const sizes = ['sm', 'md'] // <= sizes can be accessed in setup scope

export default {}
</script>
```