# How to access local component variable in defineEmits in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to run some validation on events in a VueJS component using the Composition API, as outlined [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#events-validation).

I have a component that triggers CRUD events up to a parent. The data passed in the event is an object. In particular, if the object does not contain the key `dataKey`, that should trigger the `create` event.

The issue is, `dataKey` is passed as a prop and `defineEmits` cannot access the prop variable. I get this error:

> `defineEmits()` in  cannot reference locally declared
> variables because it will be hoisted outside of the setup() function.
> If your component options require initialization in the module scope,
> use a separate normal  to export the options instead.

Here's some example code:

```
const props = defineProps({
  dataKey: {
    type: String,
    default: 'id',
  },
})
const emit = defineEmits({
  create(payload) {
    if (payload[props.dataKey]) {
       return false
    }
  }
})
```

Appreciate any help on restructuring this. I am not sure that using separate  tag will allow defineEmits to work in the same way ...

Comment: what's `this` there?

Comment: Vue has an only-for-libraries builtin `getCurrentInstance()` or something, that could help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3: \`defineProps\` are referencing locally declared variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69951687/vue-3-defineprops-are-referencing-locally-declared-variables)

Comment: @MoritzRingler ya i saw that ... no it doesn't help ... i can't declare the variable in module scope because I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: i think the point is i should do the validation in the parent component .....